# Intranet .NETCORE Web API Get Local AD Users and Exchange Calendars

Tags: asp.net-web-api, active-directory, asp.net-core, exchange-server, intranet

There are two questions here, both pertaining to .NET Core and Local AD Accounts;

I am looking to access Local AD user account's, and their information.

I am looking to get Exchange calendar events for each of these users upon request.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.  The requirement of using .NET Core has me looking to stray from any old antiquated approaches to this solution, and I am simply looking for any new techniques / Microsoft NuGet Packages to assist in this endeavor.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2089) to add System.DirectoryServices support to the .NET Core libraries.  Until that point, if your .NET Core application will be running on Windows, you can target the full .NET framework to use System.DirectoryServices.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you @davidmdem